# System notification area balloon by C++?

Tags: c++, windows, notifications, system-tray, balloon

Is there simple code to show balloon notification for C++?
I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Keep in mind that C++ is a language, not an OS, so it doesn't have any standard way of doing this. (In other words, the "system" part means you need to specify which system you want the system-specific code for.)

Comment: Did you read anything I wrote? **C++ has no "system".**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=4993) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/0af102b3-5e2e-409b-a261-7ebdb6438252). In general Google rules if you know the right words (system tray is not called "tray" -- it's "system notification area")

Comment: What should I do if I want to show balloon popup for existent tray icon? All I need is just implement balloon popup. My tray icon is already implemented.

Comment: @Almas In Delphi there are several components that let you show tray hint near the icon. I guess there are similar libraries for C++ but I am not aware. The idea is simple -- create a window and position it near tray (remember that taskbar can be located not only at the bottom of desktop). Absolutely nothing fancy.